# Listen for change on a single input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two fields and their values are being populated programmatically. I'm using the `.trigger('change')` when I change the value via JS and then listen for this change with:

`$('body').on('change', $(myInput1), function() {});`
and

`$('body').on('change', $(myInput2), function() {});`

The problem is that if I change `myInput1` both listeners are active (like I have changed both inputs).

Here's a small demo to reproduce the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    var randomValue = Math.random(0, 1) * 100;
    var holder = $(this).closest('.holder');
    holder.find('input').attr('value', randomValue);
    holder.find('input').trigger('change');
  });

  $('body').on('change', $('input[name="field_one"]'), function() {
    alert('field one has changed');
  });
  $('body').on('change', $('input[name="field_two"]'), function() {
    alert('field two has changed');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <div class="holder">
    <a href="#" class="field1">Change me</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="field_one" />
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <a href="#">Change me</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="field_two" />
  </div>

</form>
```

[and jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j1e9byn1/3/)

Comment: @PraveenKumar am sorry?

Comment: What you said is right. This is crazy. Your code is good.

Comment: If the fields aren't dynamic then attaching events to the body, then filtering is inefficent. this means jquery listens for every click event on everything under the body. You should either a) lower the scope of the selector (where you use body) or b) just use the sector to the item you want to attach a click event (if they're not dynamic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use event delegation, the second parameter to `on` should be a string which is the selector. In your case you are passing an jQuery object as the second parameter so the event registration will consider it as a data object and the handler will be registered to the `body` element and the jQuery object will be passed as `event.data` in the handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    var randomValue = Math.random(0, 1) * 100;
    var holder = $(this).closest('.holder');
    holder.find('input').val(randomValue).change();
    //holder.find('input').attr('value', randomValue);
    //holder.find('input').trigger('change');
  });

  $('body').on('change', 'input[name="field_one"]', function() {
    snippet.log('field one has changed');
  });
  $('body').on('change', 'input[name="field_two"]', function() {
    snippet.log('field two has changed');
  });


  $('body').on('change', $('input[name="field_one"]'), function(e) {
    snippet.log('handler 1:' + this.tagName + ':' + e.data.selector);
  });
  $('body').on('change', $('input[name="field_two"]'), function(e) {
    snippet.log('handler 2:' + this.tagName + ':' + e.data.selector);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <div class="holder">
    <a href="#" class="field1">Change me</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="field_one" />
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <a href="#">Change me</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="field_two" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Does this make a difference, I guessed it, but was confused whether to answer or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j1e9byn1/5/)

Do not pass second parameter as a Jquery object

Try changing the selector from

```
$('body').on('change', $('input[name="field_one"]'), function(e) {
```

to

```
$('body').on('change','input[name=field_one]', function(e) {
```

Hope it works for you.